# Disable the Vue Devtool extension tip

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I love Vue in almost every aspect but this is logged whenever I start my Vue app:

```
Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools
```

I like to have a minimal development experience and I don't need this Vue extension. I'd like to disable this tip that I find annoying. How can I proceed?

#### What I've already tried

Looking at Vue's source code, the tip is logged by:

```
if (inBrowser) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (config.devtools) {
      if (devtools) {
        devtools.emit('init', Vue);
      } else if (
        true
      ) {
        console[console.info ? 'info' : 'log'](
          'Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:\n' +
          'https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools'
        );
      }
    }
    if ( true &&
      config.productionTip !== false &&
      typeof console !== 'undefined'
    ) {
      console[console.info ? 'info' : 'log'](
        "You are running Vue in development mode.\n" +
        "Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.\n" +
        "See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html"
      );
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

Contrary to the similar `development mode` warning that can be turned off by `Vue.config.productionTip = false` before `new Vue({...})`, there doesn't seems to be a config-based escape to prevent the tip to be logged. I therefore have the following options, which don't completely satisfy me:

- change `console.log` globally to filter out this particular message → *not "The Vue Way"*
- modify the source code of Vue → *not "The NPM Way"*
- kindly ask the Vue developers to remove this → *takes time + change likely to be refused for business reasons*

Comment: Why is it a problem? You'll get this in development, its not a big deal. When you are ready to deploy switch your vue lib to the production lib.

Comment: It catches my attention everytime I looke at bugs and it takes space in the console. Not a matter of life and death, but I would like to get rid of it

Comment: *"there doesn't seems to be a config-based escape to prevent the tip to be logged"* - really? There's a similar check in the code you're showing. It's also [documented](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#devtools).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the source code you provided, have you tried the following before `new Vue({...})`?

```
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

Comment: It works indeed, thanks! Do you know if this will have side-effects on the behavior of the App?

Comment: This will just disable the use of the Vue devtools. But you don't seem to be using them (chrome or firefox plugin)

Comment: But as the tip showed in the console, you should definitely be using them, they are very useful ;)

Comment: I installed them and still get this message :/

Answer (score 3):

in chrome if you right click one of the messages and choose to hide it will toss it up in your filter so dont get messages from `vue.runtime.esm.js` anymore:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We **MUST BE PUT** this code **at the end** of "Vue javascript"

```html
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

**Example**

```html
let demo = new Vue({
  data: {},
  < Some code ...... >
});

Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

p.s. Put this code "Vue.config.devtools = false;" at the program header will be did not work.

Comment: That's what the accepted answer alsready asks to do

Comment: Nino, But I don't understand his English. So I break down the main point.